# Unity C# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `System.Math.Round(double, int)' and `System.Math.Round(decimal, int)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code. I'm getting the error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `System.Math.Round(double, int)` and `System.Math.Round(decimal, int)`

I know this is due to the result of the operation being ambiguous between a double and a decimal, but I have no clue on how to  get only a decimal as a result.

```
int enemiesThisWave= Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(TotalEnemies * (percentForWave / 100), 1));
int enemiesForType = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(lenghtList * (percentForType / 100), 1));
```

Comment: you could try to replace `100` by the decimal literal `100m`.

Comment: @Yogu this will cause a compilation error if percentForWave is a double. Speaking of which, what are the types of TotalEnemies, lenghtList, and percentForWave? I'm not certain how this call can be ambiguous.

Comment: Show us the code that declares and sets the values for `percentForWave` and `percentForType`.

Comment: It's ambiguous if `TotalEnemies * (percentForWave / 100)` results in an int that can be implicitly converted to `double` or `decimal`. This also means that an integer division is used which is probably not intentional (given the use of rounding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to cast one of your values to the type you want to invoke:

```
int enemiesThisWave = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(TotalEnemies * ((decimal)percentForWave / 100), 1));
```

or specify decimal on your `100` value:

```
int enemiesThisWave = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(TotalEnemies * (percentForWave / 100m), 1));
```

Assuming `TotalEnemies` and `percentForWave` are `int`

Comment: The second option is correct as the first hides an integer division that is most likely not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) instead:

```
int enemiesThisWave= Mathf.FloorToInt(TotalEnemies * percentForWave / 100f + 0.5f);
int enemiesForType = Mathf.FloorToInt(lenghtList * percentForType / 100f + 0.5f);
```